# Получить индексы ячейки таблицы при клике

Tags: javascript, table

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить индексы (номер строки и номер столбца) ячейки таблицы, если у меня есть элемент (`HTMLTableDataCellElement`), соответствующий этой ячейке?

(Например, я вешаю обработчик клика на всю таблицу, получаю ячейку на которую кликнули через `event.target` и затем мне нужно узнать номер строки и столбца этой ячейки)

```js
document.querySelector('table').onclick = (event) => {
  let cell = event.target;
  let i = ???
  let j = ???
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0,0</td>
    <td>0,1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,0</td>
    <td>1,1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042140/click-on-html-table-and-get-row-number-with-javascript-not-jquery

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector('table').onclick = (event) => {
  let cell = event.target;
  if (cell.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'td')
    return;
  let i = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
  let j = cell.cellIndex;
  /*let table = document.querySelector('table');
  for (var m = 0; m < table.rows.length; m++) {
    for (var n = 0; n < table.rows[m].cells.length; n++) {
      if (table.rows[m].cells[n] == cell) {
        i = m;
        j = n;
      }
    }
  }*/
  console.log(i, j);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0,0</td>
    <td>0,1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1,0</td>
    <td>1,1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```